# In R: how to pass function name (not as character) as an argument to another inner function without loss of initial function name?

Tags: r, dplyr, quoting

I have two functions:

> 1. `Worker` that does the job
> 2. `Boss` that calls the "Worker" and ask it to execute given function called by **name**

If I call `Worker` directly it receives function body and its name so it can use both. But if I call the `Worker` through the `Boss`, the `Boss` masks name of the function from the `Worker` as FUN

```
require(magrittr)    
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(one = c(1,1,1), two = c(1,3,NA))

Worker <- function(df, feature, FUN, ...) {
  newvarname <- paste0(substitute(FUN), feature)
  df %>% mutate(!!newvarname := FUN(!!as.name(feature), ...))
}

Boss <- function(df, feature, FUN, ...) {
  df %>% Worker(feature, FUN, ...)
}

Boss(df, "two", mean, na.rm = T)
   #   one two FUNtwo
   # 1   1   1      2
   # 2   1   3      2
   # 3   1  NA      2
Worker(df, "one", mean)
   #   one two meanone
   # 1   1   1       1
   # 2   1   3       1
   # 3   1  NA       1
```

I tired to play with `quote/quo/enquo/substitute/get/match.fun`, but nothing helped. Does it mean, that R cannot pass a whole function object - both name and body - as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to handle it with some `rlang`:

```
library(rlang)

df <- data.frame(one = c(1,1,1), two = c(1,3,NA))

Worker <- function(df, feature, FUN, ...) {

    if (!is_quosure(FUN)) {
        fun_q <- quo(FUN)
        newvarname <- paste0(substitute(FUN), feature)
    }
    else {
        fun_q <- FUN
        newvarname <- paste0(quo_text(fun_q), feature)
    }

    df %>% mutate(!!newvarname := eval(fun_q)(!!as.name(feature), ...))
}

Boss <- function(df, feature, FUN, ...) {
    fun_q <- enquo(FUN)
    df %>% Worker(feature, fun_q, ...)
}

Boss(df, "two", mean, na.rm = T)

  one two meantwo
1   1   1       2
2   1   3       2
3   1  NA       2

Worker(df, "one", mean)

  one two meanone
1   1   1       1
2   1   3       1
3   1  NA       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `eval(substitute())` inside of `Boss`, but it doesn't seem very satisfying

```
Boss <- function(df, feature, FUN, ...) {
  eval(substitute(df %>% Worker(feature, FUN,...)))
}

Boss(df, "two", mean, na.rm = T)
  one two meantwo
1   1   1       2
2   1   3       2
3   1  NA       2
```